# How can I make a sprite object set it's moving direction at the point of a touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

So I'm playing around and slowly making my first iOS game. I'm trying to get my sprite object to set out a straight path angled towards the location of the player (which is where the user last touched).

The code I have makes the bee move towards the player and stop when it gets to it, instead of going from one side of the screen, through the player and off the other side of the screen.

```
    var beeSpeed = 2.0

    var moveAccross = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(player.position.x,player.position.y), duration:beeSpeed)
    badBee.runAction(moveAccross)
```

I will be having many objects constantly spawning that should all set their path once to the player location at the time they spawn.

Any help would be great,

I think I figured it out, if anyone could check my code and make sure it's doing the right thing that would be great :)

```
let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: player.position.x-player.position.x-bee.size.width, y: player.position.y), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
        let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        bee.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

Comment: so each object will continue on a straight path from the spawning point to the players current position and pass through the player and then get removed when out of the screen?

Comment: does your code work?  player.position.x-player.position.x should be zero? it doesn't make sense. you have to calculate the slope from the spawning point to the player and then interpolate to somewhere outside the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate the slope from the spawning point to the player and then interpolate to somewhere outside the screen.

```
func add(location:CGPoint)
{
    let bee = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))
    bee.name = "Bee"
    bee.position = location
    self.addChild(bee)

    let slopeToPlayer = (bee.position.y - player.position.y) / (bee.position.x - player.position.x)
    let constant = bee.position.y - slopeToPlayer * bee.position.x

    let finalX : CGFloat = bee.position.x < player.position.x ? 500.0 : -500.0 // Set it to somewhere outside screen size

    let finalY = constant +  slopeToPlayer * finalX

    let distance = (bee.position.y - finalY) * (bee.position.y - finalY) + (bee.position.x - finalX) * (bee.position.x - finalX)
    let beeSpeed : CGFloat = 100.0
    let timeToCoverDistance = sqrt(distance) / beeSpeed

    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(finalX, finalY), duration: NSTimeInterval(timeToCoverDistance))
    let removeAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        bee.removeFromParent()
        println("removed")
    }
    bee.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction,removeAction]))

}
```

Comment: This is amazing thanks so much!!!
My algorithm worked but very poorly as it wasn't calculating correctly, yours works perfectly.